# In-app purchase doesn't return any response

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get products from the store.
[Screenshot of product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8yHO.png)

```
ProductDetailsResponse productDetailResponse = 
  await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(_kProductIds.toSet());
```

When I attempt to do that I don't even get a response. In debug the code just abruptly stops working.

The following

```
final bool isAvailable = await _inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
```

returns true

For iOS it works.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops working"? Does it hang, throw an error or return an unexpected value?

Comment: Literally none of this. It just exits the function. The app itself continues to work. I tried to wrap it in try-catch, but nothing changed.

Comment: Can you check if `await _inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(...).catchError((e) => print(e))` outputs something to the console?

Comment: It outputs nothing. The code after this doesn't execute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you're using in_app_purchase package? It can be buggy sometimes so I recommend using [RevenueCat](https://docs.revenuecat.com/docs/flutter) instead. It's way easier and works more smoothly.

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, it turned out that switching to this platform is easier than solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of setup steps.  But if you run this code and it turns out the problem is that it's not available, it's probably because you have an emulator that doesn't work.

```
final bool available = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
    if (!available) {
      print("store is not available");
      error = "Store not available";
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }
```

[image]
Need to get the one with the Play Store icon

[image]