# Flutter in_app_purchase stuck at queryProductDetails() method

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, revenuecat

#in_app_purchase
I'm using in_app_purchase in my flutter app.
https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase
Firstly I was using RevenueCat services for my IAP services but due to the unavailability of purchase tokens from Revenue Cat. I decided to use flutter official's in_app_purchase.
Apparently in this approach when I query for all my products from Google Play.
The program is stuck at

```
InAppPurchase.instance.queryProductDetails();
```

method and isn't giving any response. **Not even an error**.
I have also initiated the InAppPurchase instance but still, it's getting me the issue.
Can anybody please help figure this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In-app purchase doesn't return any response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69756327/in-app-purchase-doesnt-return-any-response)

Answer (score 5):

I was battling against the same problem and finally found the solution.

This part needs to be removed from the app-level `build.gradle` file in order for `in_app_purchase` to work properly. Once I removed these two lines, everything worked flawlessly.

```
def billing_version = "4.0.0"
implementation "com.android.billingclient:billing:$billing_version"
```

This it terribly misleading, since the in_app_purchase package links to the ["Getting started" guide for Google Play](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/getting-ready), which explicitly says to add these two lines.

Comment: This solution works properly. Thanks.

Comment: You're most welcome.

Comment: Ronald, how can I find you? I would like to get feedback from you about my implementation of inapp purchases? Thanks.

Comment: @MaratHakobjanyan I'm rbluethl on Twitter - feel free to reach out over there.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make some products by uploading your app to the play store.  You have to have correct app identifier.  But also your emulator must support google play store:

There are a bunch of setup steps.  But if you run this code and it turns out the problem is that it's not available, it's probably because you have an emulator that doesn't work.

[image]
Need to get the one with the Play Store icon

[image]

If you have problems, try this code to prove the problem is the emulator:

```
final bool available = await InAppPurchase.instance.isAvailable();
    if (!available) {
      print("store is not available");
      error = "Store not available";
      notifyListeners();
      return;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks - this was my issue. I added the code to test, so now I'm creating a device with Play Store capability.